# Meaning of pseudocode "$(C, S):=$"

Tags: notation, montgomery-multiplication

I've seen pseudocode of this form in the [Montgomery multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication) related theses: $(C, S) := a[j]*b[0]+C$.

What's the meaning of "$(C, S):=$", or what is the real code that was converted from this pseudocode like?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the meaning is "compute the $2n$-bit value $a[j]*b[0] + C$, and then assign the top $n$ bits to $C$ and the bottom $n$ bits into $S$

Comment: @user3042720: if that answers the question, could you accept it (and possibly upvote it)?  Thanks!